# Update multiple rows using Code Igniter with a condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table named `employee_tbl` which looks like this:

[image: The table looks like this :]

I am using Code Igniter for this project.

Model :

```
public function update(){

    $data = array(
        'floor' =>  'First'
    );

    $this->db->where('type', 'Cleaner');    

    if($this->db->update('employee_tbl',$data)) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }               
}
```

I am finding it hard to solve this, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
$data = array(
    'floor' => 'First'
);
$this->db->update('employee_tbl', $data, array('type' => 'Cleaner'));
// or
// $this->db->update('employee_tbl', $data, 'type = "Cleaner"');
```

More info in the [docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it lots of way.
Here is one of them

```
$this->db->where('type','Cleaner');
$this->db->set('floor', 'First');
$this->db->update('employee_tbl');
```

Learn more from [CI docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

Answer (score 0):

First set your data:

```
$this->db->set('column_name', $column_vale);
```

Then determine where you want to update:

```
$this->db->where('type','cleaner'); //produces where type = 'cleaner'
```

Finally update the table

```
$this->db->update('table_name');
```